# ECMAScript 2017: Parsing from nonterminal StringLiteral to String values

Tags: javascript, parsing, ecmascript-6, lexical-analysis, ecmascript-2017

I am trying to understand the translation of a string literal to a final String value (consisting of code unit values), following [ECMAScript 2017](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#prod-StringLiteral).

---

### **Relevant Excerpts**

**5.1.2 The Lexical and RegExp Grammars**

> A lexical grammar for ECMAScript is given in clause 11. This grammar
>   has as its terminal symbols Unicode code points that conform to the
>   rules for SourceCharacter defined in 10.1. It defines a set of
>   productions, starting from the goal symbol InputElementDiv,
>   InputElementTemplateTail, or InputElementRegExp, or
>   InputElementRegExpOrTemplateTail, that describe how sequences of such
>   **code points are translated into a sequence of input elements**.
>
> Input elements other than white space and comments form the terminal
>   symbols for the syntactic grammar for ECMAScript and are called
>   ECMAScript tokens. These tokens are the reserved words, identifiers,
>   literals, and punctuators of the ECMAScript language.

**5.1.4 The Syntactic Grammar**

> When a stream of code points is to be parsed as an ECMAScript Script
>   or Module, it is first converted to a stream of input elements by
>   repeated application of the lexical grammar; this stream of input
>   elements is then parsed by a single application of the syntactic
>   grammar.

and

**11 ECMAScript Language: Lexical Grammar**

> The source text of an ECMAScript Script or Module is first converted
>   into a sequence of input elements, which are tokens, line terminators,
>   comments, or white space. The source text is scanned from left to
>   right, repeatedly taking the longest possible sequence of code points
>   as the next input element.

**11.8.4 String Literals**

```
StringLiteral ::
    " DoubleStringCharacters_opt "
    ' SingleStringCharacters_opt '

SingleStringCharacters ::
    SingleStringCharacter SingleStringCharacters_opt

SingleStringCharacter ::
    SourceCharacter but not one of ' or \ or LineTerminator
    \ EscapeSequence
    LineContinuation

EscapeSequence ::
    CharacterEscapeSequence
    0 [lookahead ∉ DecimalDigit]
    HexEscapeSequence
    UnicodeEscapeSequence

CharacterEscapeSequence ::
    SingleEscapeCharacter
    NonEscapeCharacter

NonEscapeCharacter ::
    SourceCharacter but not one of EscapeCharacter or LineTerminator

EscapeCharacter ::
    SingleEscapeCharacter
    DecimalDigit
    x
    u
```

**11.8.4.3 Static Semantics: SV**

> A string literal stands for a value of the String type. The String
>   value (SV) of the literal is described in terms of code unit values
>   contributed by the various parts of the string literal.

and

> The SV of SingleStringCharacter :: SourceCharacter but not one of ' or
>   \ or LineTerminator is the UTF16Encoding of the code point value of
>   SourceCharacter.
>
> The SV of SingleStringCharacter :: \ EscapeSequence is the SV of the
>   EscapeSequence.

---

### **Question**

Assume we have string literal `'b\ar'`. I now want to follow the above lexical grammar and semantic grammar, to turn the string literal into a set of code unit values.

1. `b\ar` is recognized as a *CommonToken*
2. `b\ar` is further recognized as a *StringLiteral*
3. *StringLiteral* is translated to *SingleStringCharacters*
4. Each code point in *SingleStringCharacters* is translated to *SingleStringCharacter*
5. Each *SingleStringCharacter* without a `\` infront is translated to a *SourceCharacter*
6. `\a` is recognized as \ *EscapeSequence*
7. *EscapeSequence* (a) is translated to *NonEscapeCharacter*
8. *NonEscapeCharacter* is translated to *SourceCharacter*
9. All *SourceCharacter*'s are translated to `any Unicode code point`
10. Finally, the SV rules are applied to get string values and thus code unit values

The problem I have is that the StringLiteral input element is now:

```
SourceCharacter, \ SourceCharacter, SourceCharacter
```

There is no SV rule for **\ SourceCharacter**, only for **\ EscapeCharacter**.

Which makes me wonder if I have the order wrong, or misunderstood how the lexical and syntactic grammar is applied.

I am also confused about how the SV rules are applied altogether. Because they are defined to apply to nonterminal symbols, as opposed to terminal symbols (which should be the result after the lexical grammar has been applied).

Any help is deeply appreciated.

Comment: *“NonEscapeCharacter is translated to SourceCharacter”* Translated? Where did you get this?

Comment: Hi @Ryan. I added an excerpt at the top, clarifying where the term translate came from. As far as I understand, the lexical grammar is applied (often recursively) to nonterminal symbols, until only terminal symbols (aka. tokens / input elements) remain.

Comment: Under 11.8.4: `NonEscapeCharacter ::
SourceCharacter but not one of EscapeCharacter or LineTerminator`

Comment: I believe this: `SourceCharacter, \ SourceCharacter, SourceCharacter` to be in error. It should be this: `SourceCharacter, SingleEscapeCharacter, SourceCharacter, SourceCharacter`.

Comment: That doesn’t mean it’s not a NonEscapeCharacter (or, in turn, not a CharacterEscapeSequence and not an EscapeSequence), though. The ``\`` EscapeCharacter rule applies and directs you to the SV “The SV of CharacterEscapeSequence :: NonEscapeCharacter is the SV of the NonEscapeCharacter”.

Comment: There should be a step-by-step algorithm of how it goes from nonterminal symbols to code unit values. It's not like we can just choose where to stop the lexing process, on a case by case basis (e.g. at `\ EscapeCharacter`). As far as I understand, lexing happens first, using lexical grammar, to turn it all into terminal symbols. Then the semantic analysis is applied.

Comment: @RandyCasburn It wouldn't be a `SingleEscapeCharacter`, because it is `\a` and `a` is a `NonEscapeCharacter`.

Comment: CharacterEscapeSequence::
SingleEscapeCharacter
NonEscapeCharacter
^--- that is what the grammar says `/a` is a CharacterEscapeSequence that the lexer tokenizes as a SingleEscapeCharacter (`/`) followed by a NonEscapeCharacter - the NonEscapeCharacter is then tokenized as a SourceCharacter.

Comment: @RandyCasburn it is not both `SingleEscapeCharacter` and `NonEscapeCharacter`, it is either or. See 5.1.5 Grammar Notation: https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#sec-grammar-notation. That is not relevant to the question however. We can continue that piece in chat, if you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, assuming we're going in with a single token `'b\ar'`, which is as you've said a `StringLiteral` token. Applying the algorithm defined in [11.8.4.3 Static Semantics: SV](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#sec-static-semantics-sv) as well as [10.1.1 Static Semantics: UTF16Encoding(cp)](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#sec-utf16encoding), we follow the `SV` rules:

1. The SV of `StringLiteral::` `'` `SingleStringCharacters` `'` is the `SV` of `SingleStringCharacters`.

   - Unwrap the quotes since we're recursively running `SV` on just the `SingleStringCharacters` part, e.g. `SV(b\ar)`
2. The `SV` of `SingleStringCharacters::` `SingleStringCharacterSingleStringCharacters` is a sequence of one or two code units that is the `SV` of `SingleStringCharacter` followed by all the code units in the `SV` of `SingleStringCharacters` in order.

   This says "call SV every `SingleStringCharacter` appending results".

   1. `SV(b)`

      1. The `SV` of `SingleStringCharacter::` `SourceCharacter` but not one of `'` or `\` or `LineTerminator` is the `UTF16Encoding` of the code point value of `SourceCharacter`.

         - The codepoint "b" is codeunit `\x0062` so the result here is essentially a code unit sequence of a single 16-bit unit `\x0062`
   2. `SV(\a)`

      1. The `SV` of `SingleStringCharacter::` `\` `EscapeSequence` is the `SV` of the `EscapeSequence`.

         - Essentially `SV(EscapeSequence)` this `SV(a)` (no `\` prefix)
      2. The `SV` of `EscapeSequence::` `CharacterEscapeSequence` is the `SV` of the `CharacterEscapeSequence`.

         - Basically just passing through `SV(a)`
      3. The `SV` of `CharacterEscapeSequence::` `NonEscapeCharacter` is the `SV` of the `NonEscapeCharacter`.

         - More pass-through
      4. The `SV` of `NonEscapeCharacter::` `SourceCharacter` but not one of `EscapeCharacter` or `LineTerminator` is the `UTF16Encoding` of the code point value of SourceCharacter.

         - The codepoint "a" is code unit `\x0061`, so this results in a single-unit sequence of just `\x0061`.
   3. `SV(r)`

      - Following the same steps as for `SV(b)` this results a single-unit sequence containing `\x0072`.
3. Merging the sequence `SV(b) + SV(\a) + SV(r)` back together, the value of the string is the sequence of UTF16 code units `[\x0062, \x0061, \x0072]`. That sequence of code units results in `bar`.

#### Edit:

> I though we should first apply the lexical grammar and end up with tokens, and then subsequently apply the SV rules?

The "token" from a lexer's standpoint, is `StringLiteral`, everything within that is just information on how to parse. `EscapeSequence` is not a type of token.

`SV` defines how to break down the StringLiteral token into a sequence of code units.

As states in [11 ECMAScript Language: Lexical Grammar](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-ecmascript-language-lexical-grammar)

> The source text of an ECMAScript Script or Module is first converted into a sequence of input elements, which are tokens, line terminators, comments, or white space. The source text is scanned from left to right, repeatedly taking the longest possible sequence of code points as the next input element.

These "input elements" are the tokens used by the parser grammar.

> Assuming the order of events is right, my second questions is around SV(\a). The first escape sequence rule is applied and we are left with SV(a), which should follow the same path as SV(b) no?

There's more than just the value, there is also the datatype. Using Flow/Typescript-style annotations, you can kind of think of the steps above for

1. The `SV` of `SingleStringCharacter::` `\` `EscapeSequence` is the `SV` of the `EscapeSequence`.
2. The `SV` of `EscapeSequence::` `CharacterEscapeSequence` is the `SV` of the `CharacterEscapeSequence`.
3. The `SV` of `CharacterEscapeSequence::` `NonEscapeCharacter` is the `SV` of the `NonEscapeCharacter`.
4. The `SV` of `NonEscapeCharacter::` `SourceCharacter` but not one of `EscapeCharacter` or `LineTerminator` is the `UTF16Encoding` of the code point value of SourceCharacter.

as if it were an overloaded function, e.g.

```
function SV(parts: ["\", EscapeSequence]) {
    return SV(parts[1]);
}
function SV(parts: [CharacterEscapeSequence]) {
    return SV(parts[0]);
}
function SV(parts: [NonEscapeCharacter]) {
    return SV(parts[0]);
}
function SV(parts: [SourceCharacter]) {
    return UTF16Encoding(parts[0]);
}
```

So `SV(a)` would be kind of like `SV("a": [CharacterEscapeSequence])` whereas `SV(b)` has a different type.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Logan. My first question is around the order of things. You apply the SV algorithm right away. I though we should first apply the lexical grammar and end up with tokens, and then subsequently apply the SV rules? Of course, I might have understood that completely wrong. To contradict myself, I feel like I have read somewhere that every application of a Lexical Grammar production results in run of SV(), thus outputting a String value.

Comment: Assuming the order of events is right, my second questions is around SV(\a). The first escape sequence rule is applied and we are left with SV(a), which should follow the same path as SV(b) no? Is it necessary with the rest of the steps for that SV(a)? I.e. why do we go through `CharacterEscapeSequence` etc.. assumingly the algorithm then only sees SV(a).

Comment: That clarifies it for me Logan, thanks as always. Is there a statement in the spec stating this (or something similar): `There's more than just the value, there is also the datatype.` ? If not, where did you get that from?

Comment: SV wouldn't be defined the way it is if that wasn't how it worked. It specifically lists out the behavior of the algorithm for each type of value. If the token was broken down first before SV ran, it wouldn't make sense to define it that way.

Comment: As a side point, I found this on Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis#Evaluator. It says that a lexer first goes through each character to see which character sequences make up valid tokens (scanner phase), then the evaluator phase goes over each lexeme to produce a value, and thus create a finished token. Key point: If the evaluator sees an escape sequence in a string literal, it will run a lexer on it (so the lexer runs a lexer) to unescape the escape sequence. When unescaped, it removes the quotes and passes the literal token to the parser.

Comment: The description from Wikipedia (my previous comment) does not really tie in with how ECMAScript does it, unfortunately. ECMAScript says: Create the StringLiteral token (which may include escape sequences), then apply the SV algorithm on it to output a stream of code units. The Wikipedia description says: Escape sequences are removed before a token is created. The finished token is then passed to the parser which assumingly will evaluate the validity of the code and compile it all to code units.

Comment: The spec does not usually specific _how_ to implement something, just how things should behave. The specifics of how a lexer might work, or if the lexer is even a separate thing is entirely up to implementers.